# MySQL Tables Not Updating (PDO)

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am trying to have the PHP code update an address in user table.

For starters, using mysqli, and tried both prepared statements as well as simpler queries.  Never had much luck with prepared statements ever because I find them confusing, particularly bind_result().

I do use mysql testing at the command itself to make sure it works as it should.  Updates as it should so it's not the mysql command itself.  I even gave it a shot in phpMyAdmin locally on the server.  However, once in PHP, it doesn't update data in the table.

Immediate thought that came to mind was to make sure the 'user' accessing the mysql tables had UPDATE rights, and it does.  So it doesn't look like a permission issue.  Even when I use the mysql root with all rights and privileges, the table will NOT update.

My original attempt was some thing quite simple:

```
$query = "UPDATE `UserTable` SET `Address`=\"". $address . "\" WHERE `id`=".$id;

$conn->query($query);
```

So, I tried prepared statement version of this and had the same effect.  No error, but nothing changed in my table.

Today, I decided to go the PDO route.

```
try {

$dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostname; dbname=DBDatabase", $db_user, $db_pass);                      
$query = "UPDATE UserTable SET 'Address'='".$address."' WHERE 'id'=".$id;
echo "Query: ". $query;
$count = $dbh->exec($query);
echo $count . " record changed.";
$dbh = null;
}

catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

I also tried changing other fields (maybe it was just happening to VARCHAR fields like address).  So, I tried flipping the Registered flag and no changes register for that either.

Comment: Remove the quotes `SET 'Address'` columns can't be wrapped in quotes, including the ones in `WHERE 'id'`

Comment: Take a deep breath, back up, and figure out parameterized queries. It's worth figuring out.

Comment: @Fred-ii- That defeats the purpose of using PDO and its features, though. Although you're right about quotes around table names

Comment: I'm only stating @DamienPirsy Edit: Indeed, you're right about defeating the purpose.

Comment: How to debug - output your query to text. Copy text query and run it in the sql environment. See if it works.

Comment: When in production, always add error reporting to the top of your file(s) 
`error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` and `$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);` right after the connection is opened if you're not already doing that.

Comment: Have you tried a plain old MySQL statement either via shell commands or phpmyadmin? If so can you tell us how many records it is showing you have changed?

Comment: @Fred-ii- right on, but wouldn't that be in development? When my app is in production and actually used by coworkers, I do not really want them to see notices about undefined variables screwing the content displayed

Comment: @FélixGagnon-Grenier That's what I meant by *"When in production"* - I stand corrected. ;-)

Answer (score 3):

You're not using PDO properly. This is how you will want to form your query.

```
try {

$dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=$hostname; dbname=DBDatabase', $db_user, $db_pass);                      
$stmt = $dbh->prepare('UPDATE UserTable SET `Address`=:address WHERE `id`=:id');
$stmt->bindParam(':address', $address, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindParam(':id', $id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt->execute();

}

catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not your direct question, but prepared statements are super easy, they just require a learning curve - which, honestly, from personal experience is no steeper than learning PDO.

Traditional Query Steps:

1. DB query.
2. DB result.

Prepared Query:

1. Send DB query without parameters, to prepare.
2. Insert parameters.
3. Connect to results (bind a variable for each return column, in order).
4. Cycle through results, using variables rather than a `$result` array.

It is a few extra steps, but take the twenty minutes you need to to conceptualize it and it will all snap together. The advantage to PDO is that it works across different databases and it is great at prepared statements.